# Call method when Key pressed

Tags: java, opencv, keylistener

I am working with opencv and a video capture where I want to call a method that takes that frame based on a key press. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but when I run the program when I press the space key the image isn't being captured. Here is my code:

```
public class VideoCap implements KeyListener{

GetContours takeFrame = new GetContours();
static{
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

VideoCapture cap;
Mat2Image mat2Img = new Mat2Image();
Mat copy = new Mat();
VideoCap(){
    cap = new VideoCapture();
    cap.open(0);
} 

int frames = 0;
/*int savedCount = 0; //keep track of saved frames
String[] photos = {"first.png","second.png","third.png","forth.png",
"fifth.png","sixth.png","seventh.png","eigth.png","ninth.png"};
*/
boolean captured = false;
BufferedImage getOneFrame() {

    frames++;

    cap.read(mat2Img.mat);

    mat2Img.mat = takeFrame.captureFrame(mat2Img.mat);

    if(captured == true){
        mat2Img.mat = takeFrame.captureFrame(mat2Img.mat);
        System.out.println("WRITTEN!!!");
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("first.png", mat2Img.mat);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return mat2Img.getImage(mat2Img.mat);
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        captured = true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'd check two things, to start:  Is `getOneFrame()` being called?  And, is the `keyPressed` event firing?

Comment: getOneFrame is always called it is each frame that showed. The camera view always shows but when I press the key it never exits. @DM

Comment: OK.  So then, is `keyPressed` running?  And is `captured = true;` being run in that method, when it does?

Comment: `keyPressed` isn't responding, I even added print statements to it when it would be called and print out "Called" but it wouldn't print it out to the screen and the value of `captured` remained false. @DM

Comment: My best guess is that there's some UI element that has the keyboard focus.  So, that element is what needs to have the `keyPressed` method on it.

Comment: could I update my question and show the more code of what is the exact problem so that you can confirm your guess? @DM

Comment: Best practice would be to include an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Alright will do